# Add date field and boolean with ? in name to existing Elasticsearch documents

Tags: elasticsearch

We need to add two new fields to an existing ElasticSearch (7.9 oss) instance.

**Field 1: Date Field**

We want to add an ***optional*** date field. It shouldn't have a value upon creation.
How to do this with `update_by_query`?

Tried this:

```
POST orders/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.new_d3_field",
    "lang": "painless",
    "type": "date",
    "format": "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
  }
}
```

**Field 2: Boolean field with ? in name**

We want to keep the `?` so that it matches the other fields that we already have in ES.

Also worth noting that even removing the `?` and doing the below the field doesn't appear to be a boolean.

Tried this:

```
POST orders/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.new_b_field? = false",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Which gave the error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "script_exception",
        "reason" : "compile error",
        "script_stack" : [
          "ctx._source.new_b_field? = false",
          "                         ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script" : "ctx._source.new_b_field? = false",
        "lang" : "painless",
        "position" : {
          "offset" : 25,
          "start" : 0,
          "end" : 32
        }
      }
    ],
    "type" : "script_exception",
    "reason" : "compile error",
    "script_stack" : [
      "ctx._source.new_b_field? = false",
      "                         ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script" : "ctx._source.new_b_field? = false",
    "lang" : "painless",
    "position" : {
      "offset" : 25,
      "start" : 0,
      "end" : 32
    },
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "invalid sequence of tokens near ['='].",
      "caused_by" : {
        "type" : "no_viable_alt_exception",
        "reason" : null
      }
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Also tried:

```
POST orders/_update_by_query?new_b_field%3F=false
```

Which gave:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "request [/orders/_update_by_query] contains unrecognized parameter: [new_b_field?]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "request [/orders/_update_by_query] contains unrecognized parameter: [new_b_field?]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add two new fields to an existing ElasticSearch index that don't have value upon creation you should update its mapping using [Put mapping API](http://add%20two%20new%20fields%20to%20an%20existing%20ElasticSearch)

```
PUT /orders/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "new_d3_field": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
    },
    "new_b_field?": {
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  }
}
```

If you still want to use `_update_by_query` you should set an initial value, then the field will be added.

```
POST orders/_update_by_query?wait_for_completion=false&conflicts=proceed
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.new_d3_field=params.date;ctx._source.new_b_field = params.val",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "date": "1980/01/01",
      "val": false
    }
  }
}
```

[Update By Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) is used to update documents so I guess you can't add a field to your schema without updating at list one doc. what you can do is to set a dummy doc and update only this certain doc. Something like that:

```
POST orders/_update_by_query
{
   "query": {
    "match": {
      "my-field":"my-value"
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.new_d3_field=params.date;ctx._source.new_b_field = params.val",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "date": "1980/01/01",
      "val": false
    }
  }
}
```